# Why might _initterm miss a function pointer when compiled within visual studio 2003, but not when using msys config/build?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2003, msys

I'm currently working on a very old code base, attempting to resolve a build issue. Presently we build the projects using the msys commandline instruction `config/build`, and this works fine. However if the project is built in Visual Studio 2003 and then stepped through it behaves subtly differently:

In global scope above the `Foo` class definition is the line:

`bool Foo::init = registerDescriptor();`

(the `registerDescriptor()` method is defined in `Foo`).

When stepping through after building in msys this line is picked up by the method `_initterm` in crt0dat.c (part of the .NET 2003 source), and the code in registerDescriptor is run.

But if we build in Visual Studio 2003 and then step through then this line is ignored.

The msys build process uses the same compiler as Visual Studio, the only differences that I'm aware of are the commandline args and that msys builds folder-by-folder.

Comment: What about the linkage? Is it `extern "C"`? I.e. where you include it ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L it's not extern, it's just one .cxx file amongst many. It includes its .h and is included in a couple of other cxx and h files.

Comment: wait, are you relying on certain internal behavior here? Because I think it's up to the compiler where to insert the ctors.

Comment: Something's not right here. If `registerDescriptor` is defined in `Foo` how is it accessible without the `Foo::` prefix? Anyway you can create a short `helloDescriptor.cpp` to reproduce the issue and include it in the question.

Comment: I don't want anyone to think I've abandoned this, it's just that we're currently trying to upgrade our systems to tools and libs written within the last 10 years (farewell Fortran :o). It's a big an involved task and while this question is relevant I literally haven't had any time to dig into it any further. If I figure it out I'll post an answer, if not I'll try to add more information when I have it. If it becomes irrelevant then I'll... read the meta carefully about whether best practice is to flag for deletion or not. Thanks for reading.